# APPIUM ANDROID TESTING- using webdriver

Tags: webdriver, appium, android-testing

In appium if we are using Android driver, we can use swipe to scroll the screen.
But,iam using webdriver, **how to scroll the screen in android if webdriver is used?**

Answer (score 0):

You can perform swipe by using following code to swipe / scroll up:

```
Dimension size = this.driver.manage ()
    .window ()
    .getSize ();
int startX = size.getWidth () / 2;
int startY = size.getHeight () / 2;
int endX = 0;
int endY = (int) (startY * -1 * 0.5);
TouchAction action = new TouchAction (this.driver);
action.press (startX, startY)
    .moveTo (endX, endY)
    .release ()
    .perform ();
```

**Note:**

Even if you use AndroidDriver, in latest release of Appium Java client or any other client, they have removed swipe, zoom and similar other methods. So you need to do it yourself like in the example above.

Comment: I am getting a warning for the action object definition as  "TouchAction is a raw type. References to generic type TouchAction<T> should be parameterized", what could be the reason?

Comment: With latest Java client you need to use AndroidTouchAction instead.